# PHP Traits for interfaces

Tags: php, syntax, interface, traits

I have the next code

```
<?php

interface SimpleInterface
{
    public function method(): self;
}

trait SimpleTrait
{
    public function method(): self
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

class SomeClass implements SimpleInterface
{

    use SimpleTrait;
}
```

But PHP says that `RenderableTrait->setLayout(layout:string)` isn't compatible with `RenderableInterface->setLayout(layout: string)`

Obviously, because interface expects self as returned value, but in trait I return Trait itself and it's not compatible. Are there any solutions?

Comment: change self for SimpleInterface

Comment: @Eakethet then `return $this;` will be incompatible inside Trait.

Comment: nope. I think you dont get how trait works. Context $this from trait is the class where trait is used/called, as this class is implementing SimpleInterface it will be valid, try yourself

Comment: @Eakethet i tried both options: with self, with SimpleInterface;

Yes it works, but PhpStorms says that return $this is incorrect, because we expects SimpleInteface, but there is RenderableTrait

Comment: Made codesample as an answer, have a look

Answer (score 1):

Change you return type ***self*** for ***SimpleInterface***
https://3v4l.org/LTc8E

```
<?php

trait Test {
    public function test() {
        return $this;
    }
}

class Foo {
    use Test;
}

class Bar {
    use Test;
}

$f = new Foo();
$b = new Bar();
// object(Foo)
var_dump($f->test());
// object(Bar)
var_dump($b->test());

//So for you case
interface SimpleInterface
{
    public function method(): SimpleInterface;
}

trait SimpleTrait
{
    // This method will work only in classes that implements SimpleInterface
    public function method(): SimpleInterface
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

class SomeClass implements SimpleInterface
{
    // Traits $this is now SomeClass
    use SimpleTrait;
}

$s = new SomeClass();
// object(SomeClass)
var_dump($s->method());
```